British movie 1980s, young boy killed inside fenced in US airbase after climbing fence
This one will be difficult, because I never saw more than just the first 10 minutes or so of the movie - I'm basing this on the introduction. It was aired on Norwegian TV (NRK) sometimes in the late 1980s or early 1990s. It's possibly just a TV-movie. It's British and set in the UK.
It's about the investigation - and cover-up - after a young boy is killed inside a fenced in airbase one night. He climbs the fence - I think a boarded (not chain-link) fence (I presume it's there to hide what's going on inside) - probably so he don't have to go around. He is killed inside - I think probably by a plane as he crossed the runway (but it's also possible that it was by guards).
I guess it's also possible that the boy was snooping on the base, but I think he just wanted to cut across. I think he may have been with a friend or two, but that he's the only one climbing the fence.
The movie follows the investigation and subsequent cover-up. The problem is that the airbase got something secret going on inside it - possibly some secret new plane - which the Americans want to keep hidden. I think it's set in a pretty small town, so it's also that - foreigners vs. locals, jobs connected to the base vs. one of their own being killed.
I basically just saw him climb the fence - and possibly him being found dead the next morning. The rest is based on review and introduction.

The movie is "Defence of the Realm" (1986).
It is a British movie, set in the UK. The movie starts with two young men driving a car on a deserted road at night. A police car gives chase to them, they try to escape, but there is a traffic jam ahead on the road, so they turn to a side road that leads them to the fence of a US airbase in rural England. They stop and jump out of the car. One of them is caught by the police, but the other manages to climb over the fence into the airbase. As he tries to run away, he crosses the runway and is hit by a US bomber landing. The aircraft crashes and the boy is killed. Because of the nuclear weapons at the base they try to cover-up the incident, but a journalist (played by Gabriel Byrne) investigates. 
Boy climbs over the fence:

His buddy is caught by police outside the fence:

On the runway:

Trailer:



At the 0:19 mark: The two young men arrive at the fence and they try to escape from the pursuing police by scaling the fence.
At the 0:31 mark: The boy is crossing the runway inside the base.
Additional plot details on Wikipedia here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_of_the_Realm

"Mullen suspects something deeper at work and finds evidence of a
  cover-up concerning a near-nuclear accident and a secret US Air Force
  base."


Yes, I think this is it!  I got the fence wrong, but I remember the scene where he tries to cross the runway.  Thank you very much!

You are welcome, thanks for the follow-up.
